# RavenDB Changes API Time out

Tags: c#, .net, wpf, ravendb

I am handling changes in the RavenDB database with this code:

```
_documentStore.Changes( "databasename" ).ForAllDocuments()
    .Subscribe( change =>
    {
        using ( var session = _documentStore.OpenSession( "databasename" ) )
        {
            var obj = session.Load<object>( change.Id );
           //deal with changed object
        }
    } );
```

But for some reason after a period of inactivity (I have not been able to measure how long precisely, but roughly 15-20 minutes), it stops sending updates. I don't receive any exception, but after restarting the application, it runs fine. Is there some sort of time out I need to set? Or is there something else that might cause this?

Comment: When you say you don't receive any exception, did you actually subscribe to the OnError part of the IObservable?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It is a bug in RavenDB that was fixed a while ago.
What build are you running?

Comment: I'm running V.2.0.2360, the latest stable build on nuget

Comment: I believe the latest stable build is 2.5.2666 now?

Comment: You were right, I was running an older build. Fixed now! Thanks!

Answer (score 1):

One other thing to check -- how is ravendb configured? If it is running in asp.net and the site isn't busy app pools will shut down after 20 minutes.

Comment: It's running in a self-hosted context